# activex default files directory

Tags: mfc, activex

I have activex mfc program that is run another dll code.
Those dll use "get current directory" for files and dependences.
When I run activex from browser the current directory is begin to be "desktop".
How I can to change current directory in ActiveX ? 
(I can't change code of dll I use)

Answer (score 0):

GetCurrentDirectory is a value that might change during program execution and it is not the Location were you exe/dll resides. It is a per process value. Just read the [MSDN specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Use GetModuleHandle with the AfxGetInstanceHandle and you retrieve the full path of your module. Remove the file Name and you have the directory you are searching for.